# Estimote Beacon not able to detect in android

Tags: android, cordova, ibeacon-android, estimote, beacon

I am new in Hybrid App development using `cordova`, I am using `nodejs` for developing and building `cordova` base android app.The purpose of the app is to scan any proximity device in the range. 
The plugin **`cordova-plugin-estimote`** is used for scanning.

The javascript and html file as below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <body>
   <button onclick="test();">Click</button>
  </body>
    <head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 
 
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
 alert('Device Ready');
 startScan();
     } 
 function startScan()
 {
  alert('Scanning Started');
  function onBeaconsRanged(beaconInfo)
  {
   alert('onBeaconsRanged: ' + JSON.stringify(beaconInfo))   
  }
  function onError(errorMessage)
  {
   alert('Ranging beacons did fail: ' + errorMessage);
  }
  // Start ranging beacons.
  estimote.beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(
   {}, // Empty region matches all beacons
   onBeaconsRanged,
   onError);
 }
    </script>
  </head>
 
</html>
```

The problem I have faced is when the device ready the event `onBeaconsRanged` is calling  successfully but beacon Info. Beacons array length is always zero.

Comment: what is the API of your device? This plugin seems to work only for Android >= 5.0

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yeah its  due to android version issue in the testing device.